# Ubuntu Server 14.04 - Fstab file deleted entry

Tags: partitioning, fstab, lvm

This morning when I arrived at work the samba server shares had appeared to have gone down, after a short investigation I discovered that the partition in the LVM had become unmounted, after to speaking to someone who lives in the area it turns out a power cut happened last night and we are purchasing a UPS today to combat this in the future!

But something weirder happened yet, the entry for the mounting of the partition had been removed from the `/etc/fstab` file.

I was wondering if anyone had experienced this issue before where entries from `/etc/fstab` went missing and if so what caused it?